# Diet/exercise plan for lean bulking

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-gain, fat

I'm currently skinny fat, currently lean-bulking. My age is 16, and I weigh 62kg with 180cm (136.4 lbs, 5'9")

Normally, my diet is as follows:

1. On days I workout or if I'm active during the day, I eat up to 2000kcal
2. When I'm inactive during the day, I eat around 1650kcal

The proportions are as follows (regardless of the day)

- 50% Carbs
- 23% fat
- 27% protein
- Try for a max of 45g sugars and at least 20g fiber

I go to the gym 3x/week and do HIIT 2x/week.

Questions:

Will this diet work over the long term until I'm big enough to cut, and are there other nutrients that I need to track? What about cheat meals, and is this a good diet plan and workout program?

EDIT 1 :

Ok, Thanks for the responce.

But, from what I've seen in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqN--zcMrmQ ), this guy tells me to cut up to 20% below maintenance until I'll have 15% BF to bulk. I want to measure my BF. But a lot of people seem to do it on their hands. And because I'm skinny fat, I don't have much fat on my arms, but have a lot on my belly, love handles, etc. So how do I measure body fat on my self ? And also, I think body recomposition would work on me, since I'm a 'noobie gainer' and that would mean a little bit of a cut / stay at maintenance

Now, sorry for not specifying my program.

When I go to the gym (2x/week) I do mostly chest (bench, incline bench, push-ups, etc.) + other compound movements (deadlifts) Out of the 2 days/week that I do this, I at least 1x do a 10min HIIT on the treadmill after I do this (1min intense, 1min slower). As for the chest workout I do mostly 3 sets of 7-11 reps (to failure, rest is 35s-minute). As for the deadlifts it differs but around 5x5.

Next, at home (1x/week) I do biceps, triceps (dumbells) and body-weight training. And finally, HIIT (1x or 2x/week) I like to do a dumbell HIIT training, based on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQZJlSAuOTc I changed couple of the exercises, but It's basically really similar.

I always used to eat less than others. So it seems a lot to eat 2300kcal for me as a 16yo. So,as for the diet, I changed it recently. my TDEE was around 2000-2400 calories. But for me (as I said, for a 16 y.o. with a lot body fat it seems like a lot) But still, I now eat around 2250kcal when inactive, and around 200-400kcal more when I'm active. I track my food and as for my macros, it differs every day, but it's now around 46% carbs, 26% protein and 28% fat (of course it differs, but it stays around these numbers)

Daily, I try do not overcome 45g of sugar, and try to eat at least 22g of fiber. I eat quite a lot of Whole-grain foods (bread, toast-bread etc.) and I don't know if that's OK (it fits the diet and macros)

From what I read, I think my testosterone levels are quite low. I don't want to go to some test to see how much, but I'd like to increase the levels, so daily, I try to eat natural almonds (around 15g daily), eggs (not everyday), want to buy some kind of natural peanut butter, and other things, which could increase testosterone levels

From the time I was young, I always hated vegetables and fruits. Now I'm trying to eat as much as I can, but I just can't stand most of them. I can eat vegetables in soups, or cooked vegetables, but I'm just unable to eat some most uncooked vegetables. I'm able to eat 'raw' (uncooked) carrot, brocolli, garlic, radish, and thats about it. As I said, I eat i guess all vegetables if cooked (I dont know why that is) And fruit, I eat apple, oranges, strawberrys rarely, bananas, and again, thats about it.

Thanks in advance for the help :).

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created a second account. You can merge your accounts via the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** From your text it sounds like you want to bulk first and then cut. I doubt that you will get big with this plan. 2000 calories with 3 times gym and 2 time HIIT doesn't sound like a surplus. I cannot say anything to your plan because you didn't write how your training looks like. If you **train heavy and intesive** you will build muscle. And if you follow the right nutrition plan you will also stay (or get) lean. But it takes time.

**(2)** Yes you can **cheat from time to time**. But I would do it just **for the motivation**. If you are always forbitting yourself to eat the things you want you will quit some day.

**(3)** In my opinion the diet plan is a bit too planned out. 27% and 23% sounds way too specific for me. Maybe just tell yourself to eat around a certain amount of calories a day and always take in **carbs and protein after a heavy workout**. Your percentages sound right, but circle around with them to see what makes you feel best.

**(4)** No there are not other nutrients you need to track. You should more focus on food which makes you feel well and strong in your workouts and outside. This will bring you much more results (over time) than tracking all your nutrients.

But like I said. You didn't say anything specific about your food and especially training. I can tell you that fixing skinny fat takes time but you can absoluty do it with sustainability. Train hard and heavy to burn much calories. Try to get a little stronger every week or two weeks. Lastly, give your body the right food in the right amount.

Answer (score 1):

Your food intake is completely inadequate. Given your height/weight/age, I calculate your total daily energy expenditure at 2100kcal/day on non-workout days. Assuming a decent gym program (i.e. Starting Strength, Stronglifts, or some other linear progression barbell strength program involving squats, deadlifts and pressing) you'll probably need to initially increase your food intake to at least 2800kcal in order to get anywhere, and then you'll need to make further increases as you progress.

Without increasing your food intake, you will stop making progress within the month of training.